# Global MySQL Query Fetching rows

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Everyone I have this Global mysql query

```
$table_res =  mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECTtProduct.sProduct, tManufacturers.sManufacturer,
tSerie.sSerie, tApplication.sType, tApplication.sEngine, tApplication.sKiloWatt, tApplication.sHorsePower,
tApplication.sDate1, tApplication.sDate2 FROM tProduct INNER JOIN (tSerie INNER JOIN (tManufacturers INNER JOIN 
(tApplication INNER JOIN tApplicationProduct ON tApplication.nApplication = tApplicationProduct.nApplication) ON 
tManufacturers.nManufacturer = tApplication.nManufacturer) ON tSerie.nSerie = tApplication.nSerie) ON 
tProduct.nProduct = tApplicationProduct.nProduct WHERE sProduct = '$product'
ORDER BY tProduct.sProduct;");
```

How can I fetch rows and fields from this query, by keeping in mind that the query misses the `Where` argument.

Comment: The query is functionally useless... so fix it. the where is in totally the wrong place

Comment: `SELECT WHERE ` where is supposed to be used after from clause or after joins but not after select

Comment: What problem have you identified here? What are we supposed to fix?

Comment: Almost, now put the where statment back into the query, before the order by statment, and tell us already what do you need help with!

Comment: I Want to know if I can fetch the rows of all tables from this query?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're after something like this, although frankly I find this naming policy demented...

```
SELECT p.sProduct 
       , m.sManufacturer
       , s.sSerie
       , a.sType
       , a.sEngine
       , a.sKiloWatt
       , a.sHorsePower
       , a.sDate1
       , a.sDate2 
    FROM tProduct p
    JOIN tApplicationProduct ap
      ON ap.nProduct = p.nProduct 
    JOIN tApplication a
      ON a.nApplication = ap.nApplication
    JOIN tSerie s
      ON s.nSerie = a.nSerie
    JOIN tManufacturers m
      ON m.nManufacturer = a.nManufacturer
   WHERE p.sProduct = '$product' 
   ORDER 
      BY p.sProduct;
```